# DIV: CSS cannot rescale images

Tags: css, html

I am trying to rescale images of the following `div` but the CSS style doesn't have any effect.

The div tags:

```
            <article id="article_1">
            <div id="div_article_1_fleche_haut">
                <img src="images/haut.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="div_article_1_central">
                <div id="div_article_1_central_fg">
                    <img src="images/gauche.png" />                         
                </div>
                <div id="div_article_1_central_carte">  
                    <img src="images/r500_0.gif">
                </div>
                <div id="div_article_1_central_fd">
                    <img src="images/droite.png" />                                         
                </div>                          
            </div>              
            <div id="article_1_fleche_bas">
                <img src="images/bas.png" />                                            
            </div>              
        </article>
```

The CSS file:

```
 #div_header_main {
    width: 90%;
    overflow:hidden; /**/
    border: thin solid black;   
    padding: 5px 10px 0px 5px;
}

#div_header_left {
    width: 800px;
    float:left;
}

#div_header_right {
    width: 300px;
    float:right;
}

#div_header_right img
{
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0px;
    border: thin solid black;
    height:80px;
}​

#div_article_1_central_carte img
{
    height: 25px;
}​
```

This is the jsfiddle file:

http://jsfiddle.net/e7gvbz66/3/

Comment: update your link adding your css properties, you've forgotten them

Comment: You can set a % width on images to force them to scape. E.g. `img {width: 100%;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your CSS file on [jsfiddle.net/e7gvbz66/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/e7gvbz66/8/) its working fine now. Unnecessary characters were present in your CSS file, I have removed and just added some styles to show the changes.

```css
#div_header_main {
 width: 90%;
 overflow:hidden; 
 border: thin solid black; 
 padding: 5px 10px 0px 5px;
}
 
#div_header_left {
 width: 800px;
 float:left;
}

#div_header_right {
 width: 300px;
    float:right;
}

#div_header_right img
{
    float:right;
    clear:right;
 padding: 10px 0 0 0px;
 border: thin solid black;
 height: 80px;
    /*added for testing*/
    width: 40px;
}

#div_article_1_central_carte img
{
    /*updated for testing*/
    height: 55px;
    width: 100px;
}

#div_article_1_central_carte
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include a style like this in your CSS file then the style of img will apply correctly.

```css
#div_article_1_central_carte {
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for answers. I have updated the .css file on http://jsfiddle.net/e7gvbz66/6/ The problem is still occurring. I would like the .css file properties to reduce the images sizes.
That is the structure:

I have the following div that contain a picture.
`<div id="div_article_1_central_carte">  
    <img src="images/r500_0.gif">
</div>`
And at each side of this picture I have a `div` containing a small picture on which I can click to initiate an event. So I have 4 differents `div` around the `div_article_1_central_carte`